# iPhone Screen Dimensions Considerations

Tags: ios

Sorry, I feel this will be pretty basic answer.

As I understand it the iphone screen is 320 x 480 points.

The status bar is 20 points high.

Does this not mean that your working space should be 460 points high?

It's just that when I drag out an imageview, even with the status bar visible, the panel on the right says it is 480 points high.

Also, how best to allow for extra bars at the top, (such as personal hotspot connected), I believe they push the screen down? Should all images be set to aspect fit or something?

Comment: Note that it's 320x480, not 360x480.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  you can manually change the size of imageView in the attributes inspector

2) When you drag an imageView out onto your xib, it fill up the entire screen automatically even if there is a top navigation bar
You can just manually change the size
3) Yes all objects are automatically set to aspect fit as imageView automatically resizes

Comment: So in Storyboard it's showing the image view underlapping the status bar and at run time it squashes it down 20 points??

Comment: I ask because I don't know whether the background image I'm designing should be 480 pixels high or 460...

Comment: You can simply try using the simulator 
But when you are in storyboard you can simply go to attributes inspector and set dimensions to imageView to however height you want it to be

Comment: the dimensions are under the Ruler looking tab in Attributes inspector

if i helped you please accept :)

Comment: so just to be clear, if I'm designing a launch image, or a background image, in an app where the status bar is visible, I should design for 320 x 460 points?

Comment: if you are designing a launch image 
it should be the full resolution of the screen

if you are designing for app with status bar 
then yes 320x460